# Bullet train from Tokyo to Osaka (with stopovers)

Tags: japan

I am planning a trip from Tokyo to Osaka, with a stopover at Nagoya for 2 nights to travel to Takayama, and continue to Osaka.
Should I do one more stopover at Kyoto or is a day trip better?
Also, can I book a single trip from Tokyo to Osaka and hop on and off at Nagoya and Kyoto?

Comment: For Tokyo -> Nagoya (stopover) -> Osaka, what tickets do I have to buy for the single train ticket with stopovers? One base fare and 2 bullet train tickets?

Comment: That is right. But your base fare ticket is only valid for 4 days so be very careful.

Comment: There are two questions here; the first one is unclear and probably opinion-based.

Comment: Base fare ticket is only valid for 4 days, so the maximum number of days I can stay in takayama is 4 before continuing to Osaka?

Comment: Sorry, the first article attached in your answer is helpful, but this other article I read (http://paulstravelpics.blogspot.com/2017/06/advanced-japan-how-to-hop-on-hop-off-jr.html?m=1) says to not pass through the gate as ticket will get swallowed up. What do I do?

Comment: That article is wrong. If the ticket is not returned, it means you made a mistake in your planning and stopovers are in fact not allowed for your trip

Comment: Say you buy your ticket and get to Nagoya on day 1. Assuming you use the Limited Express Hida to get to Takayama, you will get there on late day 1. You stay there for 2 days, and you continue your trip on day 3. So you can stay in Takayama & Nagoya for at most 3 nights.

Comment: I see, thank you for clarifying that the article is inaccurate.

Comment: You mentioned “assuming you use the Limited Express Hida”, can I book the Nozomi bullet train (Tokyo to Osaka, and alight at Nagoya) instead? Does it work the same?

Comment: Worth noting that ‘Should I do a stopover at Kyoto or is a day trip better’ is opinion-based and thus not answerable.

Comment: You seem very confused. You cannot go to Takayama with just a base fare ticket for Tokyo-Osana (Tokaido Shinkansen) because it's not on the route. What you can do is make a stopover at Nagoya and purchase additional tickets from Nagoya to Takayama and back (though I'm not sure it would come out cheaper than Tokyo-Takayamz plus Takayama-Osaka).

Comment: The Nozomi bullet train will not take you to Takayama. The Limited Express Hida will take you to Takayama from Nagoya.